# Create a user in Linux and FreeBsd in a non-interactive way

Tags: linux, freebsd, users

in Linux I can do this to create a new user and allow it to call sudo:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -g group1 user1
usermod -a -G sudo,www-data user1


# /etc/sudoers
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

How can I do the same in FreeBsd?

```
useradd
useradd: Command not found.
```

Note that I don't want an interactive way to create a user -- adduser -- because I want to be able to run it from a bash script without having to type any details in the terminal.

update:

It's FreeBsd 11.

Answer (score 3):

## FreeBSD, TrueOS, and relatives

- `pw useradd user1 -g group1 -s /usr/local/bin/bash`
- `pw usermod user1 -G wheel,www-data`

Or simply

- `pw useradd user1 -g group1 -s /usr/local/bin/bash -G wheel,www-data`

Note that the FreeBSD port of sudo normally configures `wheel` not `sudo`.  Also note that you'll have to install the Bourne Again shell from ports/packages.  Finally note that `pw usermod` has no notion of appending to the secondary group list.  One has to set the *entire* list.

### Further reading

- [`pw`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pw&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-stable).  FreeBSD 11.0 Manual.

## OpenBSD

- `useradd -g group1 -s /usr/local/bin/bash user1`
- `usermod -G wheel,www-data user1`

Or simply

- `useradd -g group1 -s /usr/local/bin/bash -G wheel,www-data user1`

Note that you'll have to install sudo from ports/packages.  The OpenBSD tool that comes in the operating system is `doas` nowadays.  Also note that you'll have to install the Bourne Again shell from ports/packages.  Finally note that OpenBSD's `-G` option to `usermod` always implies appending.  To set the entire secondary group list, one uses `-S`.

### Further reading

- [`useradd`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.9/man8/useradd.8).  OpenBSD 5.9 Manual.
- [`usermod`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.9/man8/usermod.8).  OpenBSD 5.9 Manual.

Comment: is it applicable for FreeBsd 11 also? Or is there a better way to do that in FreeBsd 11?